# Laurent series of an analytic function divided by $z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series, singularity-theory

This is a probably basic question about Laurent series.  Say $g(z)$ is an analytic function, that $g(0) = 0$, and $f(z) = g(z)/z$.  My textbook says $z = 0$ is a removable singularity of $f(z)$.

A removable singularity is defined as a singularity where the principal part of the Laurent series is zero.  The Laurent series is:

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_k (z-z_0)^{k}$$

$$c_k = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(\xi)}{(\xi - z_0)^{k+1}} d\xi$$

The "principal part" of the Laurent series refers to the terms where $k \le -1$.  Now if I look at the terms $k=-2, -1, 0$ of the Laurent series of $f(z)$ around $z = 0$:

$$c_{-2} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C g(\xi) d\xi = 0$$

(This follows from Cauchy's integral theorem and the fact that $g$ is analytic.)

$$c_{-1} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{g(\xi)}{\xi} d\xi$$

$$c_{0} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{g(\xi)}{\xi^2} d\xi$$

Now it seems to me that $c_{-1}$ is not zero.  Therefore, the principal part is not zero, and $z=0$ is a pole of order one.

Any hint or pointer as to where my reasoning goes wrong would be welcome.

Comment: If $g$ is analytic (in $0$), then $f(z) = g(z)/z$ has a removable singularity in $0$ if and only if $g(0) = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: It is given that $g(0) = 0$.  How do you apply that fact to make $z=0$ a removable singularity?

Comment: If $g(0) = 0$, you have $\lim\limits_{z\to 0} \frac{g(z)}{z} = g'(0)$, so $f$ is in particular bounded in a punctured neighbourhood of $0$, and that means the singularity is removable.

Comment: "A removable singularity is defined as a singularity where the principal part of the Laurent series is zero." Yuck! What book is that? Anyway, it also works with that definition well enough. $g$ being analytic means the principal part of the Laurent series of $g$ is zero. $g(0) = 0$ means $a_0 = 0$. So the Laurent series of $f$ is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}z^n$ if $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is the Laurent series of $g$.

Comment: @AWertheim, DanielFisher: Awesome, I get it now!  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DanielFischer will you post an answer so it can be upvoted? This will then remove the post from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some other assumptions on the function $g(z)$, otherwise there's no reason a priori to expect that $z = 0$ is a removable singularity of $g(z)/z$.

For instance, $g(z) = 1$ is analytic, but $f(z) = 1/z$ has simple pole (not a removable singularity) at $z = 0$.

Comment: It's also given that $g(0) = 0$ (I'll add it to the question.)